# How to implement an OAuth 2 consumer for FB and G+ and IN and TT

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0

Can anyone explain or point to some documentation on the GET / POST requests together with the message bodies + parameters + headers needed for authenticating a consumer with each of the following providers: Facebook, LinkedIn, Google, Twitter?

Note:
I am looking for framework agnostic steps, required to authenticate an OAuth 2 consumer.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn doesn't yet support OAuth 2.

We have a getting started guide in Java, Python and PHP here - this does include a link to the OAuth spec, which is really what you're looking for.
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide

Since you're looking for a language agnostic general guide, Taylor Singletary's original "OAuth Zero To Hero" slide deck might be just the thing:
http://www.slideshare.net/episod/linkedin-oauth-zero-to-hero

Answer (score 0):

Twitter [does not support OAuth2](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/397) either, unless you are using [Anywhere](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome#login-signup) - but that is not agnostic.

It seems that right now only Google, Facebook and Microsoft Accounts are supporting OAuth2, which is a shame. You will have better luck with OAuth 1, but the flow is more complicated.